# Best XML Parser with SOAP Request/Response Support

Tags: c++, c, xml, soap

I am looking for Best XML parser with support for XSD and Namespace along with SOAP Support. Looking for small footprint(ideally upto 500kB). I came across gSOAP, but not sure if *Standard Open Source Edition* of gSOAP supports all the features I am looking for.

Any help if much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a good question.

First: if you use xml/soap/wsdl based web services, you have probably a really highlevel project, and thus even the c++ isn't really sure an optimal choice. I think it is very unlinkely, if you want to develop a real, working software in C, which makes soap services. IMHO you could think about java.

Second: xml and soap/wsdl are two different things, although soap uses xml for communication and the interface description (wsdl) is xml, too.

For xml handling, I suggest you could use libxml++ .

For SOAP, there is more library, but most of them isn't enough good for me to name them. Try each after the other, and sometimes you will have luck. :-)

Both libs have small footprint - they are relative complex, but don't need a legion of another libraries.